# Sql Server View show records with no data in certain tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I have tables Products, Sales and ProductsInStores. ProductsInStores table keeps track of how many Products there are in each store. And I have a SalesProductsInStoresView with columns from tables Sales and ProductsInStores.

But there are also Products that come from a different chain of stores, so there's no ProductsInStores record for these products. So when the sale is made SalesProductsInStoresView doesn't show Sales if a Product doesn't have a ProductsInStores record.

Can I make my View show Sales with no ProductsInStores record, and just show empty cells on ProductsInStores columns, and if this is not possible what maybe other options do I have, I'm using Asp.Net MVC and Sql Server 2008.

Comment: You probably need a `LEFT JOIN`, but since you've not shown us the *current* view definition, we're unlikely to make a good guess at writing the updated one.

Comment: Please add the current code of the view OR at least the table structure, but I agree. The answer is use LEFT JOIN between Sales and ProductsInStores. But you can see a code as a result if you give us a code where to start.

Comment: thanks guys, `LEFT JOIN` did it for me, I had `INNER`. How do I accept your answers, or should I answer my own question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Left Outer join

```
Select a.field1,b.field2
from tablea A
left outer join tableb b on b.fieldc = a.fieldc
```

this allows data to be returned from the inner table whilst maintaining a join to the outer table even if there is no data present.